# How to translate hex to utf-8

Tags: ruby, utf-8, translate

I want to translate a string in hex to utf-8, for example,`"\\XB6\\XAB..."` to `"中国"`. I use `"\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f".unpack("Z*")` → `"hello"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: [`String.force_encoding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-force_encoding)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Ruby 1.9, use `String#force_encoding`:

```
"\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd".force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

Comment: i use the force_encoding code,but nothing happend.i puts the string,the ruby print the string like this "\\xe4\\xb8\\xad\\xe5\\x9b\\xbd",but when i insert the string data in my database,the value is "\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd".

Comment: Oh...so you literally have hex escapes...that's a rather different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use double quotes to define your string, otherwise you will not get the result you expect.

Example using double quotes:

```
"\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd".force_encoding("UTF-8")  =>  "中国"
```

Example using single quotes:

```
'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd'.force_encoding("UTF-8") => "\\xe4\\xb8\\xad\\xe5\\x9b\\xbd"
```